# How to join a layer and a table, on-the-fly, in the ArcGIS Server JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, attribute-joins

I have a polygon feature layer and a table, both stored in ArcGIS Online. Is it possible to join them on-the-fly in the ArcGIS Server JS API?

For example, here are some sample ArcGIS Server services for:

- a [US States polygon layer](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2)
- a [census values table](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5) for each state

Is it possible to join the layer and the table, and therefore to symbolize the polygons using the table's values?

Comment: Since this is just sample data, how frequently will your real data be updated? That will be a big factor in deciding how to proceed.

Comment: @JeffJacobson the dataset may be updated frequently. I assume from your comment you're suggesting that I need to flatten the datasets, eg join them in ArcMap and publish the joined table to ArcGIS Online? I was hoping it would be possible to do the join programatically, to avoid this if at all possible

Comment: One thing you could do would be to load the data the first time the user visits the site, do the two queries, and then store the joined results in the browser's local storage using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

Another thing you can do to improve performance is to do the queries and join in a separate thread using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API).

Comment: ...You won't be able to use the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to do the queries in a Web Worker, though. You'll need to [query the ArcGIS Servers' REST APIs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Query_Map_Service_Layer/02r3000000p1000000/) directly. [I have some code on GitHub that demonstrates how to do this.](https://github.com/WSDOT-GIS/download-arcgis-features)

Comment: @JeffJacobson thanks for the tips. I was hoping to avoid this due to the large size of the datasets but maybe it's necessary to just publish the joined tables directly to ArcGIS Online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got around to answering this one. This solution uses 2 separate queries to fetch the geometry and attributes, then joins the JSON arrays to form a combined layer definition.

[image]

```
app = {};
app.map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "gray",
  center: [-80, 38],
  zoom: 5
});
app.spatialReference = new SpatialReference({wkid:4326});

app.map.on("layers-add-result", function(results) {
  console.log("Added joined layer to map")
});

app.sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
  new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,
  new Color([255,0,0]), 2),new Color([255,255,0,0.25])
);

// Request the geometry
var geomParams = {
  where: "1=1",
  outFields: ["state_name"],
  returnGeometry: true,
  f: "json"
}

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  data: geomParams,
  url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2/query/",
  success: function (data1){
    console.log("Got geometry");
    app.data1 = data1;

    // Now request the attribute data
    var tableParams = {
      where: "1=1",
      outFields: "*",
      returnGeometry: false,
      f: "json"
    }

    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: "callback",
      data: tableParams,
      url: "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5/query/",
      success: function (data2){
        console.log("Got attributes")
        app.data2 = data2;

        // Join the geometry to the attributes
        $.extend( true, app.data1, app.data2 );
        console.log("Joined geometry to attributes");

        // Create a feature layer from the joined JSON
        app.featureCollection = {
          layerDefinition: {
            geometryType: app.data1.geometryType,
            spatialReference: app.spatialReference,
            objectIdField: "ObjectID",
            fields: app.data1.fields,
            drawingInfo: {
              renderer: {
                type: "simple",
                symbol: app.sfs
              }
            }
          },
          featureSet: {
            features: app.data1.features,
            geometryType: app.data1.geometryType,
            spatialReference: app.spatialReference
          }
        };
        var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Attributes", "${*}");  
        app.featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(app.featureCollection, {
          id: "Joined Layer",
          infoTemplate: infoTemplate
        });
        app.map.addLayers([app.featureLayer]);
      }
    });
  }
});
```